# How to center a webpage for only certain device width? i.e mobile device = center but desktop view would remain normal

Tags: html, css

I'm new to using @media but i am trying to get a webpage to respond centered for smaller devices only. while the larger width display can remain normal.
my webpage is mastercontrolunit.com and seems to appear fine on desktop view. but on phone for example the view starts all the way to the left, when i would prefer it to start centered. 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a media query for this, like below:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .centered-el {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Change `600px` to be the width of the screen you want everything to start being centered at. 
Within this media query, you write your CSS to make things be centered.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply! however i tried that and even at 219px it starts showing the page from the left. on a android in chrome. but i do think it should do what you said it would. i'm definitly doing something wrong.

Comment: No worries! Try placing the media queries at the bottom of the CSS code. Also, you might need to target your elements very specifically to make this work, like `body .parent-element .child-element`. Failing this, does it work if you use `!important` on the CSS values?

Comment: yes! i tried that and it is trying to center the left side where it already starts to begin with.i need to set where i want it to center i guess... but what tag etc would i use?